# SQL server script using IF ELSE error out when using link server connection

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on a data migration script in SQL where we have to deal with multiple databases with multiple tables.
wanted to create a generic script with all the tables we need to migrate over.
problem is, not all the databases will contain every table.
so I went the route of checking if the table exists, if exists, do the data copy.

it works well until it has to pull data across from a LINK server. It seems that it ignores ALL if conditions when it has to take the LINK server into account.

```
IF (exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'local_ArCreateLinesLog')
and exists(select * from [SQVM\KUS1].[CAPE].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = 'local_ArCreateLinesLog'))    
BEGIN
declare @cnt as int, @cnt1 as int
select @cnt=count(*) from Local_ArCreateLinesLog where local_ArCreateLinesLogSqlID = (select sqlserver from sqlservers where hostname = 'SQVM\KUS1' and databasename = 'CAPE')
--print 'KUS5 Local_ArCreateLinesLog Record Count: ' + cast(@cnt as varchar(5))
select @cnt1=count(*) from [SQVM\KUS1].[CAPE].[dbo].[Local_ArCreateLinesLog] where local_ArCreateLinesLogSqlID = (select sqlserver from sqlservers where hostname = 'SQVM\KUS1' and databasename = 'CAPE')
--print 'KUS1 Local_ArCreateLinesLog Record Count: ' + cast(@cnt1 as varchar(5))
--if @cnt <> @cnt1
--BEGIN
    print '!!!!COUNTS DONOT MATCH!!!!'
--END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print 'Table Local_ArCreateLinesLog Does Not Exist in this Partner'
END
```

If I comment out the line that contains the connection to the LINK server, it runs fine and obeys the IF constraint.
If the LINK server is in there, I get error message stating:

```
Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "SQVM\KUS1" does not contain the table ""CAPE"."dbo"."Local_ArCreateLinesLog""
```

Which is true, the table does not exist in link server which is why the if statement at the beginning of the process.

So my question is if there is something that I am missing to make this sql script obey the IF condition when dealing with a LINK server.

Both SQL servers are 2008R2 and patched to the same level.

Comment: check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4a612497-0519-4b6e-a2aa-bb6cc8bf4ce0/linked-server-permissions-error?forum=transactsql

Comment: The query parser attempts to verify all parts of the query when it is being compiled, which is how this result occurs. To fix this, you need to make the `COUNT(*)` queries dynamic queries instead. SQL Server doesn't validate dynamic queries before reaching the step in execution where the code runs.

Comment: @CR241 I am using the the fully qualified name for the SQL link servers so don't feel that is what is causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Change this

```
IF (
    EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'local_ArCreateLinesLog' )
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [SQVM\KUS1].[CAPE].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'local_ArCreateLinesLog' )
)    
BEGIN ...
```

to this

```
IF (
    EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'local_ArCreateLinesLog' )
)    
BEGIN ...
```

And then change this

```
SELECT @cnt = COUNT( * ) FROM Local_ArCreateLinesLog WHERE local_ArCreateLinesLogSqlID = ( SELECT sqlserver FROM sqlservers WHERE hostname = 'SQVM\KUS1' AND databasename = 'CAPE' );
```

To this

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @cnt = COUNT( * ) FROM Local_ArCreateLinesLog WHERE local_ArCreateLinesLogSqlID = ( SELECT sqlserver FROM sqlservers WHERE hostname = ''SQVM\KUS1'' AND databasename = ''CAPE'' )', N'@cnt INT OUTPUT', @cnt=@cnt OUTPUT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @cnt = 0;
END CATCH
```

Working with linked servers can be very quirky. The reason your IF/EXISTS was failing is that SQL Server compiles the meta prior to execution, which, as in your case, fails when the table doesn't exist. You cannot trap compile errors in a TRY/CATCH block either, hence calling sp_executesql which doesn't compile first and has the added benefit of being trapped and handled.

Comment: that is what I have done now and it is working as needed. Thanks